# How to detect when a thread hits a breakpoint in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, breakpoints, detection

Let's say I have a thread (Critical) running.  Let's say I have another thread (WatchDog) in the same process that periodically checks if Critical is processing jobs quick enough or if it has spent > X seconds on 1 job.  If Critical is spends > X seconds on 1 job, then WatchDog grabs the call stack of Critical, some other diagnostic information and reports a bug.  (One place I use this is to detect if the Swing UI thread hangs.  I use this in other performance sensitive places in code.)

If I attach a debugger (e.g. Eclipse), set a breakpoint and Critical hits the breakpoint, then WatchDog will report a bug because Critical takes too long.  How can I make WatchDog detect that Critical hit a breakpoint and not report a bug?

Currently, I simply disable WatchDog when running on a development machine; otherwise, I will get a lot of bug reports (errors logged to the console on development machine).  If I simply detect that a debugger is attached, then WatchDog will almost always end up disabled since that is how I run the program.  So, detecting an attached debugger is not sufficient.

I could set a breakpoint in WatchDog right before it reports a bug.  I could then allow WatchDog to resume if it detected an actual bug.  This is okay but I am looking for something a little more automated.

The JVM knows that the thread hit a breakpoint.  How do I inspect this state?

Note: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5422018/how-can-i-detect-whether-a-debugger-is-attached-and-a-breakpoint-has-been-set) is the same but for .Net.

Comment: "Currently, I simply disable WatchDog when running on a development machine" sounds like a good idea. What's the difference between having it running but not bothering to report errors (because it knows its in debug) and not having it running at all?

Comment: You cannot detect it. You can set a configuration option saying you run in debug though

Comment: Well, what information would that watchdog thread provide during debugging? The debugger itself might slow down the code in general, another thread might get blocked or at least slowed down by the one you're currently inspecting etc. - simply disabling the watchdog once the debugger runs sounds like a good idea since its results would be more than questionable anyways. Btw, the accepted answer to the question you've linked basically gets to the same conclusion: time critical operations and running a debugger don't fit will together.

Comment: @Michael If the WatchDog runs and logs the diagnostic information but not report a bug, then I can look at the diagnostic information and fix the problem.  If the WatchDog does not run, then I get no diagnostic information to fix the problem.

Comment: @Thomas The WatchDog captures the call stack of the Critical thread and the call stacks of the rest of the threads.  It also captures the time the Critical thread started the job, the current time, the event the Critical thread is working on and the name of the job (if applicable).  I tried pausing the Critical thread in the debugger but by the time I am able to press the button the Critical thread has recovered.  Perhaps, the current workaround is to enable the WatchDog on my development machine when I am hunting down a problem.  I wish there were an automated way to ignore breakpoints.

Comment: Well, as I already stated timing during debugging sessions is bound to be off and that can go as far as preventing racing conditions that otherwise would be likely to occur (or the other way round). Thus whenever the debugger is running your watchdog is bound to get wrong results. If you can detect whether the debugger is running (that probably depends on how you attach the debugger to the process) you could make your watchdog disable anything during that time.

Comment: @Thomas I already have a solution in place that disables the WatchDog on developer machines.  What I want is a smarter WatchDog that does not flag a hang when the Critical thread hits a breakpoint.

Answer (score 0):

From what I know you can't receive debug information unless you are registered to received receive Debug events from the JVM, so you might have to write your own agent.

Failing that, this is a little hacky, but as mentioned in the .NET question, if you are using Eclipse, you can use a condition on the breakpoint at Critical to set a System property, "com.acme.critical-stopped" or something when the breakpoint is hit.[[image]]

Then, the WatchDog thread can check the system property to see if it is set before filing a bug. 
On the line after the breakpoint you would need to set a *second* conditional breakpoint. This condition will [always return false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42278177/debugging-in-eclipse-variable-snapshot-without-breakpoint/42428552#42428552) so the Critical thread won't stop again, it will just change the system property back to false.
[image]

Try the code below with the breakpoints set where indicated and it works for me.

```
public class T1 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            int i = 0;
            while (i < 1000){
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println("Stopping");
                System.out.println("Finished");

            }
        }
    }, "WatchDog").start();


    while (true){
        System.out.println("Stopped ? " + System.getProperty("IsStopped"));
        try {
            Thread.sleep(300);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

}